# My code doesn't execute on start

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I need to draw formulas after an applet has started, so I try to do the next:

```
public class SearchIdeaApplet extends JApplet {

    private JPanel mRootPanel;
    private JButton mPrevButton;
    private JButton mNextButton;
    private JButton mUpdateButton;
    private JPanel mPlotPanel;
    private JPanel mFormulaPanel;

    private void drawFormulas() {
        TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula("x^2 + 3*y^2");

        // render the formula to an icon of the same size as the formula.
        TeXIcon icon = formula
                .createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);
        icon.setInsets(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        // now create an actual image of the rendered equation
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        jl.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        icon.paintIcon(jl, g2, 0, 0);
        // now draw it to the screen
        Graphics g = mFormulaPanel.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(this::initSwing);
        } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onUpdateButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        drawFormulas();
    }

    private void initSwing() {
        setContentPane(mRootPanel);
        drawFormulas(); //It doesn't work
        mUpdateButton.addActionListener(this::onUpdateButtonClick);
    }
}
```

But `drawFormulas()` call in `initSwing()` hasn't any effect. But if I press `mUpdateButton` my formulas are shown.
How to wait when GUI will be ready to draw formulas?

Comment: General tips/queries: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: .. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) **Did you notice `java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.` at any stage?**

Comment: @AndrewThompson, it's because my customer wants to it was an applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, nope, I didn't. But seems I was needed to call `invalidate` on my panel.